# Can I upgrade to OSX 10.9 and format my HD along the way?

Tags: macos, partition, formatting

I want to upgrade from ML to Mavericks but I want to erase and format my HD to a single partition along the way. Is this possible?

Answer (score -1):

Yes you can use disk utility to reformat the Macintosh HD partition during the installation of Mavericks, however if you want to create a new partition using disk utility the you will have to create a Mavericks install USB so you can boot from there.

You can't create a Partition when booted from the same drive hence the need to boot from a USB installer.

Creating a USB installer is as follows, Format the USB thumb drive as a Mac OS Extended (Journaled) and name the USB thumb drive Untitled

Download Mavericks from the Mac App Store,

Copy and paste this command into terminal,

sudo /Applications/Install\ OS\ X\ Mavericks.app/Contents/Resources/createinstallmedia --volume /Volumes/Untitled --applicationpath /Applications/Install\ OS\ X\ Mavericks.app —nointeraction

Comment: You're wrong. You can load up Internet Recovery and make any changes to the file system from that. It replaces the need for a USB installer.

Comment: Wrong about what? What part of my answer is wrong?

Comment: "You can't create a Partition when booted from the same drive hence the need to boot from a USB installer." You don't need a USB installer with Internet Recovery.

Answer (score -1):

If time (and bandwidth) is not an issue, you could upgrade your current drive to 10.9 first, which would also create the 10.9 recovery partition.  Then, after booting into the 10.9 recovery partition, you could partition the drive via disk utility and then cleanly (re)install 10.9.

Comment: I'm downloading now. Then I was thinking to just install it and erase  whatever that's old. Is that what you mean?

Comment: No ... I meant to follow these instructions AFTER you've installed 10.9 for the first time:  http://support.apple.com/kb/PH14243     This will redownload the OS again, and go through the installation process a second time.  From another Apple support page (http://support.apple.com/kb/ht4718): "If you use the Recovery System stored on your startup disk to reinstall OS X, it installs the most recent version of OS X previously installed on this computer."  That's why you would need to first go through the regular 10.9 installation first.

Comment: Using Internet Recovery is a better option. It will save you a lot of time and you won't need to install OS X twice.

Comment: @cksum, As stated in the second link above, "If you use Internet Recovery to reinstall OS X, it installs the version of OS X that originally came with your computer"; not an upgraded version.

Comment: That's not true. It consults the recovery partition and takes it's cues from that. If you have Mvx installed, it will pull Mvx down. That info is consulted upon load, safe from reformat.

Comment: Ok ... assuming that's correct (and, I'm not completely convinced) can you explain how to get the 10.9 recovery partition onto the hdd without first installing 10.9 ?